# Problems with parsing directory as argument

Tags: python, bash, argparse

I have a program in python which iterates over all of the files in a directory, which I give as an argument. I also set up an argument parse function in my python file. When I try to run that python file with bash script and directory as an argument I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 93, in <module>
    args['inverse transformation path'], args['line'])
  File "main.py", line 68, in main
    transform_path, inverse_path, line)])
  File "main.py", line 65, in main
    for filename in os.listdir(image_directory):
NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: 'test1/2020-03-11-11-45-37-576.jpg'
```

I am running the python script with:

```
python3 main.py -imd 'test1' -pp points.csv -rpp transformed_points.csv -tp transformation_matrix.csv 
-itp inverse_transformation_matrix.csv -l 2
```

That is the function I am running.

```
def main(image_directory, points_path, real_points_path,  transform_path, inverse_path, line):
    data = []
    index = 0
    for filename in os.listdir(image_directory):
        if filename.endswith(".jpg") or filename.endswith(".png"):
            data.append([filename, analysis_main(os.path.join(image_directory, filename), points_path, real_points_path,
                                    transform_path, inverse_path, line)])
            index += 1

    df = pandas.DataFrame(data)
    df.to_csv("razdalje.csv", sep=',', header=False, index=False)
```

and parsing

```
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-imd", "--image directory", required=True,
    help="directory with images")
ap.add_argument("-pp", "--points path", required=True,
    help="path to the csv file with pixels used for declaring coordinate system")
ap.add_argument("-rpp", "--real points path", required=True,
    help="path to the csv file with points on the ground used for declaring coordinate system")
ap.add_argument("-tp", "--transformation path", required=True,
    help="path to the csv file with matrix used for transforming space")
ap.add_argument("-itp", "--inverse transformation path", required=True,
    help="path to the csv file with inverse matrix used for transforming space")
ap.add_argument("-l", "--line", required=True,
    help="declaring on which lane is the analysis being done, 1 -> left lane 2 -> right lane")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
```

and running the code with

```
main(args['image directory'], args['points path'], args['real points path'], args['transformation path'],
     args['inverse transformation path'], args['line'])
```

Comment: Could you share the code in which you do parsing and path transformation?

Comment: This code still does not show what is calling `main()` and thus what is being passed as `image_directory`.

Comment: Interesting. If I use the same code, the error I get is expected (since `test1` is, in fact, not a directory where I'm working, but it would be in your case). How does this code differ from yours then such that you are getting an error related to a `jpg` file and I'm not? https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/e79f5f4d-7188-44c8-87b6-4c85325c9a9d/?i=true

Comment: I can't see any differences...

Comment: Do any of these methods we can't see the implementation for (`analysis_main`, for example) in turn call `main` again? The stack trace you gave looks 3 deep, but the code as we currently see it would only have a stack trace that's 2 deep.

Comment: Yes, there was the problem with analysis_main, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

We don't know how you're walking through your filesystem, but the file listed obviously is not a directory, it's an image. Add a safety check like so before inspecting:

```
if os.path.isdir(image_directory):
    for filename in os.listdir(image_directory):
```

I'd suggest you [look into `os.walk()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_walk.htm), as it does this work for you.

Comment: The problem is that the argument is a directory for sure, but for some reason instead of the argument I give, first item in image_directory is taken as the name of the directory.